# Type expected identifier expected

Tags: c#

I'm doing this project for uni.
I'm having an error, which I don't know how to fix.
Thanks for any help

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EmployeeID,TitleOfCourtesy,FirstName,LastName,Title,BirthDate,HireDate,Address,City,Region,PostalCode,Country,HomePhone,Extension,ReportsTo,Notes")]) {
        var employee = _context.Employees.ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            _context.Add(employee);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(employee);
    }
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: You need to declare the type and name of the parameter that you intend to pass to `Create`. For example, `Create(string id)`.

Comment: More specifically, `Create(Bind(...)] Employee employee)`

Comment: ok, Thank you :D